# TableView SearchController not showing on top of screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I've created a simple tableView and set a searchController. I need my tableview y point to starts with 70px. When i touch searchBar its not showing the opened bar on top of the screen. Instead it moves up slight from 70px.

Am not familiar with swift or storyboard. I'd like to use objective c language.

Method:ViewDidLoad

```
cateArray_ = [ [ NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Fruits", @"Vegetables", @"1", @"350", @"Shell", @"Stocks", @"Numbers", nil ];

self.tableView_ = [ [ UITableView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 70 ) style:UITableViewStylePlain ];
self.tableView_.delegate = self;    
self.tableView_.dataSource = self;    
self.tableView_.bounces = YES;    
self.tableView_.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;    
UIView* footerToRemoveBorderLine = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ];   
self.tableView_.tableFooterView = footerToRemoveBorderLine;  
self.tableView_.backgroundColor = [ UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0 ];    
self.tableView_.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);   
[ self.view addSubview:self.tableView_ ];  
[ self setTitle:@"Category" ];

//Search controller
self.searchCtrl_ = [ [ UISearchController alloc ] initWithSearchResultsController:nil ];   
[ self.searchCtrl_ setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:false ];   
[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar sizeToFit ];  
[ self.searchCtrl_ setSearchResultsUpdater:self ];  
[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault ]; 
[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ];
[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar setDelegate:self ];
[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"Alpha", @"Numbers", nil ] ];
self.tableView_.tableHeaderView = self.searchCtrl_.searchBar;
```

Methods Search delegates

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    [ self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchCtrl_ ];
}  

// Called when the search bar becomes first responder
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    // Set searchString equal to what's typed into the searchbar
    NSString* searchString = [ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar text ];
    NSString* scope = [ [ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar scopeButtonTitles ] objectAtIndex:[ self.searchCtrl_.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex ] ];    
    [ self filterContentForSearchText:searchString Scope:scope ];
}
```

When i open the searchBar by tap it moves the gray part of search only a little on open. But i want it to be on top or just below status bar.

Can someone help me with what i did wrong or any work around.

I need table y point of tableView to start at 70 because above table view i will keep some scope bar and a text.

Pardon for my bad English and much appreciated for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
//try the below code
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UITableView*tableView_;
    UISearchController*searchCtrl_;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView_ = [ [ UITableView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain ];
    //tableView_.delegate = self;
    //tableView_.dataSource = self;
    tableView_.bounces = YES;
    tableView_.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    UIView* footerToRemoveBorderLine = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ];
    tableView_.tableFooterView = footerToRemoveBorderLine;
    tableView_.backgroundColor = [ UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0 ];
    tableView_.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [ self.view addSubview:tableView_ ];
    [ self setTitle:@"Category" ];

    //Search controller
    searchCtrl_ = [ [ UISearchController alloc ] initWithSearchResultsController:nil ];
    [ searchCtrl_ setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:false ];
    [ searchCtrl_.searchBar sizeToFit ];
    [ searchCtrl_ setSearchResultsUpdater:self ];
    [ searchCtrl_.searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault ];
    [ searchCtrl_.searchBar setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo ];
    [ searchCtrl_.searchBar setDelegate:self ];
    [ searchCtrl_.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"Alpha", @"Numbers", nil ] ];
    tableView_.tableHeaderView = searchCtrl_.searchBar;
}
```

Comment: give content offset to (0,0) and dont minus the tableview height